# Distinguish project languages for Nuget source code packages

Tags: c#, vb.net, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

Let's say I want to build a Nuget package which puts source code files to the Visual Studio projects it gets installed to. Well this works pretty fine with [the "content"-approach](https://blog.nuget.org/20160126/nuget-contentFiles-demystified.html).

That means I can bring these files in the following folder structure to automatically add them to the file system and the VS-projects as well:

```
.\ThePackage.nuspec
    └ content\TheFile.cs
    └ content\TheOtherFile.cs
```

With a package like this, Nuget will automatically add the source code files to the projects directly. However, it does that with **both** files, so I found no way to make that conditional.

**"Why?"** you may ask - well, I don't really have two `cs` files. I have one for C# and one for Visual Basic doing the same in different languages. So I need to distinguish between C# and Visual Basic project files. The content approach above with a structure like this ...

```
.\ThePackage.nuspec
    └ content\TheFile.cs
    └ content\TheFile.vb
```

... will cause a mix with the `cs` and the `vb` file in each project, of course.

Is there a way to tell Nuget that I just want to have the `cs` file in C# projects and the `vb` file in Visual Basic projects without the need to provide two Nuget packages like `ThePackage for C#` and `ThePackage for VB`?

Comment: You can add a init.ps1-file to your nuget-package that is executed on installation. There you can place some logic like detect what language is used in the project etc and removed/add the unwanted or wanted files

Comment: I solved it - if you would post this as answer, I could give you some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a init.ps1-file to your nuget-package that is executed on installation. There you can place some logic like detect what language is used in the project etc and removed/add the unwanted or wanted files

Comment: I added my own answer to provide some source code (it's too small in the comments). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For all visitors searching for a solution. With the powershell approach suggested by @D.J., I ended up with that script below.

---

The nuget package has two content files:

```
content\XXXXXX.cs
content\XXXXXX.vb
```

With this, both get installed by Nuget (to the file system and the VS project).

Afterwards, I run the following script to delete the unused file again.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)


# All XXXXXX code files (for C# and VB) have been added by nuget because they are ContentFiles.
# Now, try to detect the project language and remove the unnecessary file after the installation.


function RemoveUnnecessaryCodeFile($project)
{
    $projectFullName = $project.FullName
    $codeFile = ""
    $removeCodeFile = ""

    if ($projectFullName -like "*.csproj*")
    {
        $codeFile = "XXXXXX.cs"
        $removeCodeFile = "XXXXXX.vb"
        Write-Host "Identified as C# project, installing '$codeFile'"
    }

    if ($projectFullName -like "*.vbproj*")
    {
        $codeFile = "XXXXXX.vb"
        $removeCodeFile = "XXXXXX.cs"
        Write-Host "Identified as VB project, installing '$codeFile'"
    }

    if ($removeCodeFile -eq "")
    {
        Write-Host "Could not find a supported project file (*.csproj, *.vbproj). You will get both code files and have to clean up manually. Sorry :("
    }
    else
    {
        # Delete the unnecessary code file (like *.vb for C# projects)
        #   Remove() would only remove it from the VS project, whereas 
        #   Delete() additionally deletes it from disk as well
        $project.ProjectItems.Item($removeCodeFile).Delete()
    }
}

RemoveUnnecessaryCodeFile -Project ($project)
```